# Visual Studio Code behind a proxy with pip install

Tags: python, pip, proxy

I try to install a package behind a company proxy in visual studio code on windows on python.

The error I get is:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(10054,
> 'An existing connection was forcibly close d by the remote host',
> None, 10054, None))

I did the settings under windows for the proxy and for example the proxy server is:
`http://gia-proxy.company.net` with the port `8080`.
I am able to log on into the browser and I am able to use the internet, so the problem must be in the pip. somehow when I run: `pip config debug`
I get the output:
e

> nv_var: env: global:   C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini, exists: False site:
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\pip.ini, exists:
> False user:   C:\Users\user\pip\pip.ini, exists: False
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini, exists: False

And I am also not able to install it with:

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@ttp://gia-proxy.company.net:8080 TwitterApi
```

with my username and password and it leads to the same error.